# Holding reference of ViewDataBinding in Fragment/Activity causes Memory Leak

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-databinding

I have a Fragment like this

```
class AFragment: Fragment(){
  lateinit var binding: AFragmentBinding

  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.a_fragment, container, false)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this // this line should make the [binding] observes the fragment lifecycle
        return binding.root
  }
}
```

And the binding object always leak after the Fragment is destroyed

Here is the log

[image]
The binding variable actually lives in an abstract Fragment and has a generic type (T: ViewDataBinding) so set binding = null at onDestroyView is not an option =))

Do you guys have any idea how can I resolve this?